# Initialize a static private map as empty

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a `static map` that is a `private` data member. How do I initialize it in the implementation file so that it's initial containers are empty? It is not `const`. It is important that nothing is in this container at start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Header:

```
class XXX {
private:
    static std::map<X,Y> the_map; // declares static member
// ...
```

Implementation file:

```
std::map<X,Y> XXX::the_map; // defines static member
```

That will insert a constructor call for your map into your program initialization code (and a destructor into the cleanup). Be careful though - the order of static constructors like this between different translation units is undefined.

Comment: It says that my map is private and so the default initialization at the top of my CC file is invalid.

Comment: I had to move my typedef to public, but kept my member private. That fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

How about this (if I understand you correctly):

```
std::map<T,T2> YourClass::YourMember = std::map<T,T2>();
```

Comment: Or just `std::map<T,T2> YourClass::YourMember;`

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Exactly. Just clarifying that you could give constructor arguments if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

If you *declare* it in the class definition, then you have to *define* it in the implementation:

`--- test.h ---`

```
// includes and stuff...
class SomeClass
{
    private:
        static std::map<int,std::string> myMap;
};
```

`--- test.cpp ---`

```
std::map<int,std::string> SomeClass::myMap; // <-- initialize with the map's default c'tor
```

You can provide an initialization, too:

```
std::map<int,std::string> SomeClass::myMap = std::map<int,std::string>(myComparator);
```

Comment: Nitpick: That would be /declared/ in the class and /defined/ in the implementation.