# Static map initialization

Tags: c++, static, stdmap

I have the following code:

```cpp
//MyClass.h
class MyClass {
public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, int> OpMap;
    static OpMap opMap_;     
    // (more methods)
};

//MyClass.cpp
//Init opMap_
MyClass::opMap_["x"] = 1; //compilation error
```

How can I (statically) initialize `opMap_`?

Comment: whats the compilation error you get?

Comment: see that [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c)

Comment: @Need4Sleep : on VS10 ,I get "error C2057: expected constant expression","error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0"

Comment: @didierc - I saw that.It didn`t help

Comment: @Yakov: is this a new version of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463825/using-array-of-value-type-for-the-stlmap)?

Comment: @Mr.C64 : IT is different question ,since the way of initialization cahnged

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++, can I statically initialize a std::map at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172053/c-can-i-statically-initialize-a-stdmap-at-compile-time)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're using C++11, you could use initializer lists:

```
//MyClass.h
class MyClass {
public:
      typedef std::map<std::string, int> OpMap;
      static OpMap opMap_;
};

//MyClass.cpp
MyClass::OpMap MyClass::opMap_ = { 
    { "x", 1 }
};
```

If you don't have access to a compiler that supports the C++11 standard, you could do the following:

```
//MyClass.h
class MyClass {
public:
      typedef std::map<std::string, int> OpMap;
      static OpMap opMap_;
private:
      static OpMap init_map() {
          OpMap some_map;
          some_map["x"] = 1;
          return some_map;
      }
};

//MyClass.cpp
MyClass::OpMap MyClass::opMap_ = init_map();
```

Comment: @mfontanini : I know that,but I use VS10

Comment: @mfontanini : Ok.Thanks - I understand I need a kind of init map.Can you guide me about the function content?

Comment: @Yakov it basically creates a local map, initializes it with what you want and returns it by value. You then initialize your static member `opMap_` using the result of calling that function.

Comment: Just in case, somebody is looking to initialize an empty map -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247407/initialize-a-static-private-map-as-empty

Comment: thanks ... _still_ must use c++98 on some projects, smh

Answer (score 5):

As you are using VS2010, you need to initialize your static member in MyClass.cpp, in front of any other member function definitions. call `MyClass::InitMap()` if you want to initialize `opMap_`.

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(void);
  ~MyClass(void);
public:
   typedef std::map<std::string, int> OpMap;
   static OpMap opMap_;    
   static void InitMap();
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
std::map<std::string, int> MyClass::opMap_;
MyClass::MyClass(void)
{
   InitMap(); // just sample if you want to initialize opMap_ inside MyClass constructor
}

void InitMap()
{
  MyClass::opMap_["x"] = 1;
}
```

Comment: it is not clear.Please give more details.What you wrote looks like declaration I already have in MyClass.h

Comment: it's very clear. It's a definition of static member and it calls default std::map constructor. In your MyClass.h, it's static member declaration not definition.

Comment: @bills - OK ,I got about defintion .But even if I do std::map<std::string, int> MyClass::opMap_;
and immidiatly want to init omMap_ : MyClass::opMap_["x"] = 1; I get the same compilation error

Comment: You need to do operations inside functions. see my updated answer

Comment: This is a bad solution. You'll be initializing the map each time a `MyClass` object is constructed.

Comment: @billz I did as you said but it still gives compilation error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'

Comment: Don't tell me you didn't `#include <string>` in MyClass.h?

Comment: It's not a bad solution if you add a static bool to see if the map is already initialized...

Answer (score 4):

In C++ 17 you can add inline

```
//MyClass.h
class MyClass {
public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, int> OpMap;
    inline static OpMap opMap_;     
    // (more methods)
};
```

Comment: `inline`, shortest possible solution, this answer should be at the top.